# How to cite published university course using a .bib file in Harvard/ authoryear-ibid style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, harvard-style

I am trying to cite an MIT opencourseware lecture as a .bib file, and trying to reference it in Harvard style (in LaTeX we call it ibid?, but sorry for my unawareness, this is my firt time using LaTeX)

It should look somehow like this:

Winston, P. (2010) 'Lecture 13: Learning: Genetic Algorithms' [Recorded Lecture]. 6.034: Artificial Intelligence. Massachusetts Institute of Technology. Fall 2010. Available at: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/index.htm (Accessed: 1 January 2022).

I am a beginner user, it is my first document using LaTeX, so any help will be much appreciated! - and Happy New Year to everyone!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Thank you Mico, I've been using this so far for my book and article sources: \usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}.